# Is there any way to organize Slack channels for everyone?

Tags: slack

We are using Slack as our community "hub", instead of a more traditional forum.  This is primarily because there is a significant barrier to entry when someone has to click "New Topic" and then present a structured, formal topic for discussion.  In Slack they just jump in and talk, which is great for engagement.

But there is a real problem with organization.  Over time we have grown and the number of channels is getting out of hand.  Currently we have 55 channels which should be divided into roughly a half doze top-level groupings/categories.  Except Slack only allows for that at the per-user level.

Is there any way for us as administrators, to organize the channels into any sort of hierarchy at all?  So far my efforts to find a solution have come up empty but I'm hoping maybe someone here has some ideas.

Comment: Have you already reviewed [Manage channels | Workspace Administration](https://slack.com/help/categories/200122103#manage-channels)?

Comment: Yes I have, not helpful unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the official answer appears to be, no. Slack provides no options for organizing channels into folders or sub groups except at the individual per-user level.

[Here is their support page demonstrating that each user can organize their channels themselves any way they want.](https://slack.com/help/articles/360043207674-Organize-your-sidebar-with-custom-sections)

[A Quora discussion specifically about how you cannot put Slack channels in folders.](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-put-Slack-channels-in-a-folder)

[Here is a nice thorough article explaining how to keep Slack organized, and that it's entirely about channel naming conventions.](https://slack.com/blog/collaboration/how-to-use-slack-channels-to-organize-your-work)

[Here is a great article detailing why Slack is not a good tool for building a community.](https://guild.co/blog/slack-isnt-designed-for-communities-and-heres-why/)

[And another with additional reasons why Slack is a poor choice for a community.](http://martinb3.io/slack-is-bad-community)

[Here is a forum post about how poor Slack is for building a community, with many excellent jumping-off points in the comments.](https://www.indiehackers.com/post/slack-isnt-a-good-community-building-tool-a3fd726a7f)

We will be moving away from Slack in the new year, looks like we'll be using Zulip instead.

Comment: Please add the source or brief description of what lead you to this conclusion.

Comment: Lots of Internet searching, forums, and talking with other slack users.  When I am back at my computer I will see if I can provide some actual citations.